# Is there a good way of getting MethodInfo of open generic method?

Tags: .net, reflection, metaprogramming

Consider type like this one

```
public interface IHaveGenericMethod
{
   T1 Method<T1>(T1 parm);
   T2 Method<T1,T2>(T1 parm);
   int Method2(int parm);
}
```

How do I get a methodInfo for its methods?
for a regular non-generic method, like method2, I can go with

```
typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMethod("methodName",new Type[]{typeof(itsParameters)});
```

for a generic method though, I can't, since it's parameters are not types per-se.
So, how do I do that?
I know that I can call

```
typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMethods()
```

to get all methods of that type, and then iterate over that collection and do some matching, but it's ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: re "but that does not answer my question" - maybe, but see "But nothing cleaner." - i.e. AFAIK you can't really get a lot cleaner than that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get MethodInfo of a generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326136/how-to-get-methodinfo-of-a-generic-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they *are* types - of sorts:

```
    foreach (var method in typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMethods())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
        if (method.IsGenericMethodDefinition)
        {
            foreach (Type type in method.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> " + type.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

So you can check by the number of args, and check the signature. But nothing cleaner.

Comment: well, yeah, but that does not answer my question

Comment: (replied to original question so it appears on your list...)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out the MSDN page "[Reflection and Generic Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/609yztkt.aspx)".

> since it's parameters are not types per-se

Actually, I think it's because you want to query *type* parameters, but the type list you can provide to `GetMethod()` is not for type parameters.

Also, remember that all you need to select a "method group" of generic methods is to know the number of generic type parameters.  So you can just count them.

> then iterate

Don't iterate, query:

```
       var mi = from mi in typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMethods()
                where mi.Name == "Method"
                where mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition
                where mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2
                select mi;
```

Comment: this is sneaky, but it still can return more than one method. Also it requires LINQ, ergo .NET 3.5, which is what I wanted to avoid.
The only improvement I could think of is, instead of typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMethods()
use typeof(IHaveGenericMethod).GetMembers(lots,of,arguments)

Answer (score 0):

I personaly do the following:

```
public static MethodInfo ExtractMethodInfo<TDeclaringType, TMethod>(Expression<Func<TDeclaringType, TMethod>> methodAccessExpression) {
    return (MethodInfo)((ConstantExpression)((MethodCallExpression)((UnaryExpression)methodAccessExpression.Body).Operand).Object).Value;
}
```

---

```
var genericQueryMethodInfo = ExpressionHelper.ExtractMethodInfo<DbContext, Func<IQueryable<object>>>(context => context.Query<object>).GetGenericMethodDefinition();
```

This way, you are sure to find the right one, and I think it's better than iterating over all methodInfos.