# ExpressionTree creation for y => ConstantCollection.Any(x => y.Contains(x)). Different scope parameterExpressions

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to create an ExpressionTree from one constant string array and one parameter.

```
var keys = "car,train".Split(','); // "car, train" will be given as a constant.
//var myModel = "MyModel-car"; // this will be given as a parameter
myModel => keys.Any(k => myModel.Contains(k)); // how to create this ExpressionTree?
```

I've read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326321/how-do-i-create-an-expression-tree-calling-ienumerabletsource-any), but my case is different because the delegate (`k => myModel.Contains(k)`) has actually two parameters. Here, the `k` is determined by `keys` which is a ConstantExpression at runtime. But in the Expression body, it is still a ParameterExpression instance.

I've tried like:

```
var modelParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string)); // Example value: "MyModel-car".
var keys = "car,train".Split(',').AsQueryable().Expression;

var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
                                  .First(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1)
                                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
var containsMethod = typeof(String).GetMethods()
                                   .Where(x => x.Name == "Contains" && x.GetParameters().Length  == 1)
                                   .First(x => x.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == typeof(string));
var key = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
var containsCallExpr = Expression.Call(modelParam, containsMethod, key);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(containsCallExpr, key);

Expression anyCallExpr = Expression.Call(keys, anyMethod, lambda); // throw an exception
Expression expr = Expression.Lambda(anyCallExpr, modelParam);
```

However, the `anycallExpr` line throws an exception:

> Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance

Does anyone know how to make this work?

**[UPDATE]**

Based on @Svyatoslav Danyliv's suggestion, I changed the order of argument but a different exception is shown:
`Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Any[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' (Parameter 'method')`

- I think this exception makes sense because I have two parameters actually.

Comment: Use other overload: `Expression.Call(anyMethod, keys, lambda)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I've tried your suggestion, but I have another exception as I updated on my original question.

Comment: My inner lambda (`k => myModel.Contains(k)`) does not have to know about `myModel` parameter because it will be given as a constant when it needs to run.  I don't know how to deal with this situation. All other examples are handling exactly one variable.

Comment: What you are trying to generate at the end? Some extension method? I can build any LINQ expression dynamically but I need to understand why it is needed and maybe there is better solution.

Comment: I'm trying to create a Condition(Rule)Engine which collect all conditions and produce an aggregated Expression and a DataProvider which returns parameter data holder. One of the existing rule is that, for a given model, it checks if the model name has some special keyword from a given list of keywords.

Comment: We expect that this ConditionEngine can provide some dynamic rule controls. For example, at runtime, remove certain rules depending on the real-time requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following realization:

```cs
var modelParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "model") ; // Example value: "MyModel-car".
var keys       = "car,train".Split(',').AsEnumerable();

var keysExpression = Expression.Constant(keys);

var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods()
    .Where(x => x.Name == nameof(string.Contains) && x.GetParameters().Length == 1)
    .First(x => x.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == typeof(string));

var key              = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "k");
var containsCallExpr = Expression.Call(modelParam, containsMethod, key);
var lambda           = Expression.Lambda(containsCallExpr, key);

Expression anyCallExpr = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any),
    new[] { typeof(string) }, keysExpression, lambda);

Expression expr = Expression.Lambda(anyCallExpr, modelParam);
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much! So, `Expression.Lambda()` can take only directly related ParameterExpression! I need to study the last `Call` method. Thank you again, @Svyatoslav Danyliv!

Comment: Actually my first suggestion also should work, you have just retrieved wrong `Any()` overload.

Comment: oh, thank you for the comment. I will check the `Any()` method.