# Why is there not a `fieldof` or `methodof` operator in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

They could be used as follows:

```
FieldInfo field = fieldof(string.Empty);
MethodInfo method1 = methodof(int.ToString);
MethodInfo method2 = methodof(int.ToString(IFormatProvider));
```

`fieldof` could be compiled to IL as:

```
ldtoken <field>
call FieldInfo.GetFieldFromHandle
```

`methodof` could be compiled to IL as:

```
ldtoken <method>
call MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle
```

Whenever the `typeof` operator is used, you get perfect Find All References results. Unfortunately, as soon as you go to fields or methods, you end up with nasty hacks. I think you could do the following... or you can go back to getting a field by name.

```
public static FieldInfo fieldof<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return (FieldInfo)body.Member;
}

public static MethodInfo methodof<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    MethodCallExpression body = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Method;
}

public static MethodInfo methodof(Expression<Action> expression)
{
    MethodCallExpression body = (MethodCallExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Method;
}

public static void Test()
{
    FieldInfo field = fieldof(() => string.Empty);
    MethodInfo method1 = methodof(() => default(string).ToString());
    MethodInfo method2 = methodof(() => default(string).ToString(default(IFormatProvider)));
    MethodInfo method3 = methodof(() => default(List<int>).Add(default(int)));
}
```

Comment: Can you imagine how many times a year this feature would be used?

Comment: I'm writing a CLI implementation in C# - it would be extremely helpful for identifying special references in the IL in the JIT so I can treat them differently. For example, I want to replace any IL instance of `call RuntimeHelpers.get_OffsetToStringData` with `ldc.i4 <int32 offset>` inline (before native code generation).

Comment: Fine. How many times a year would this feature be used, worldwide?

Comment: It's a quite frequently requested feature, so apparently there are reasonably common usage cases. That said, obviously would not achieve the popularity of, say, auto props, or where clauses.

Comment: @Eric: I saw on your blog people requesting it for Reflection.Emit - I've run into it there as well. :) On a side note, the C# compiler should compile "typeof(int).TypeHandle" to simply "ldtoken <typeref int32>" without going through the property. (sorry I don't know the exact MSIL syntax).

Comment: It would be an extremely used feature for anyone dealing with WPF (think dependency properties), and, more generally, anyone implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Even people who don't use WPF still throw `ArgumentException`

Comment: @ChrisKerekes obviously true, but how is that relevant here?

Comment: @280Z28 My previous comment was in response to the comment of @PavelMinaev. The `ArgumentException` constructor overload that takes two strings uses the name of the offending parameter the same way that a `DependencyProperty` is registered. This demonstrates that the need of `fieldof` operator would be of significant use to a broader range of developers besides simply those working on WPF applications.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335126/compile-time-reflection-in-c-sharp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229597/why-not-a-memberinfo-reflection-function-for-c-sharp?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256309/property-of-aka-infoof-via-rosyln

Comment: Mind you this approach has a corner case (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658669/lambda-expression-not-returning-expected-memberinfo). I think we're better off not inventing undocumented behaviour.. For methods, I like the solution given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329433/get-methodinfo-for-any-method-with-any-signature-delegate-for-any-signature

Comment: @JohnSaunders see how many questions are there on stackoverflow related to reflection of type members. In all those cases this is a useful feature. In fact the number of duplicates for this very same requirement itself is too many..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eric Lippert (on the C# design team) has an excellent overview/discussion on this topic [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue.aspx). To quote:

> It’s an awesome feature that pretty much everyone involved in the design process wishes we could do, but there are good practical reasons why we choose not to. If there comes a day when designing it and implementing it is the best way we could spend our limited budget, we’ll do it. Until then, use Reflection.

Comment: 'Foof' would've been a more appropriate expletive :)

Comment: I added a comment under my question with a use case that would be extremely helpful. Of course it could be used - it would just be extremely helpful if I could write C# code to fully leverage the `ldtoken` IL instruction. Or `cpblk` and `initblk` for that matter.

Comment: I know, I'll implement the hack, then add those helper methods to the list of calls I treat in a special way before the JIT! The only downside is it results in a small JIT-time performance hit, clumsy syntax, and a slightly larger assembly.

Answer (score 38):

You can actually avoid using both reflection and lambdas (.NET Framework 2.0). Consider the following class:

```
public class methodof<T>
{
    private MethodInfo method;

    public methodof(T func)
    {
        Delegate del = (Delegate)(object)func;
        this.method = del.Method;
    }

    public static implicit operator methodof<T>(T methodof)
    {
        return new methodof<T>(methodof);
    }

    public static implicit operator MethodInfo(methodof<T> methodof)
    {
        return methodof.method;
    }
}
```

and it's usage:

```
MethodInfo writeln = (methodof<Action>)Console.WriteLine;
MethodInfo parse = (methodof<Func<string, int>>)int.Parse;
```

Comment: +1 For a very elegant solution, plus style points for overloading the cast operators to make it look more built-in.  Now if only C# would let us explicitly reference the get/set accessors on properties then this would work on those as well.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work

Comment: @hazzik It works for me. Please specify the error.

Comment: I agree it's nice, but unfortunately this requires you to explicitly specify the method signature, so it's basically the same as `MethodInfo parse = ((Func<string, int>)int.Parse).Method;` which is fully built-in and thus doesn't require any helper class. Seems to me, the whole point here is to avoid that cast, which would enable you to actually ***obtain*** the signature at runtime when all you need to provide at compile-time is the method name token.

Comment: I have problem with `void` (non returned) method.

Answer (score 7):

@280Z28 - We were just sitting down to figure out how to do this when I found your question & code.  We needed a PropertyOf method so I added it.  Here it is in case anybody else needs it. Thx for the great question.

```
     public static PropertyInfo PropertyOf<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
        PropertyInfo pi = body.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi != null)
        {
            return pi;
        }
        else throw new ArgumentException("Lambda must be a Property.");
    } 

      [TestMethod()]
    public void MethodofPropertyOfTest<T>()
    {

        string foo = "Jamming";
        MethodInfo method1 = ReflectionHelper.Methodof(() => default(string).ToString());
        PropertyInfo prop = ReflectionHelper.PropertyOf(() => default(string).Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(method1.Invoke(foo, null), "Jamming");
        Assert.AreEqual(prop.GetGetMethod().Invoke(foo, null), foo.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Nicely done. I did something similar here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods/373396#373396

but I like yours as a solid general solution:

Comment: Something to note if you need this type of operation in production code - the value returned by a call to methodof, fieldof, or propertyof is constant for a given input. Whenever I need them in a class, I either have a static readonly field that I initialize to the FieldInfo/MethodInfo/PropertyInfo, or I use an appropriate `Dictionary<Type,MemberInfo>` map. If you look at the IL generated by the expression tree sugar, you can see you don't want to be running that unless you have to. The #1 advantage I see of having them as language operators is the IL could/would be very succinct.

Comment: Corner case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658669/lambda-expression-not-returning-expected-memberinfo. I think this is not the right approach for this kind of work. Also i think its better to check for unary expressions as in cases of boxed conversions like `<object> () => IntProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a generic type version, that can use F2 to rename and not need modify existed code
in the example, the method name is GetPKValue

```
var typFactory = typeof(FormFieldFactory<>).MakeGenericType(entity.GetType());
var methodName = new Func<object, object>(FormFieldFactory<object>.GetPKValue).Method.Name;

var theMethod =
    (Func<object, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(Func<object, object>)
        , typFactory.GetMethod(methodName)
    );
```