# How do you make a System.Linq.Expressions.Expression object containing a call to Any()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I want to dynamically generate a linq.expressions.expression statement which I can use as a filter.

Here is a sample Linq query that I'd like to convert to an Expression:

```
ctx.customer.where(c=>ctx.Invoice.Any(i=>i.customerId == c.id));
```

Here's my attempt

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
var c = Expression.parameter(typeof(Customer),"c");
var i = Expression.parameter(typeof(Invoice),"i");

var rightPart= Expression.Equal(
 Expression.propertyorField(i,"customerId"), Expression.propertyorfield(c,"id")
```

Please assist.

Comment: using LinqExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

Answer (score 8):

When I need to manually create linq expression I just make .Net create for me such expression from lambda and then I can explore its structure. For example run under debug

```
Expression<Func<TestObject, bool>> expression = t => t.Invoice.Any(i => i.CustomerId == t.Id);
```

and inspect expression variable.

Comment: Nice idea but I don't understand the debugview. Do you have some link to explain ?

Comment: Maybee is there a way I can combine the Expression<> with a bynaryExpression ?

Answer (score 5):

I assume that `LinqExpression` comes from `using LinqExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;`.

There is no specific expression type for `Any`, because it is not an operator or the like.  `Any` is a static method, so you should create a `Call` expression for that.

You will need to build the expression based on the static method syntax rather than the extension method syntax:

```
ctx.customer.Where(c => Enumerable.Any(ctx.Invoice, i => i.customerId == c.id));
```

There are a lot of steps to this.  Here it is in outline, because I don't have time to work out all of the steps correctly.  I'm not entirely sure how to represent the fact that the `c` parameter used in the inner lambda is not a parameter of that lambda, but rather of the outer lambda.  In outline, you'll need to

1. Retrieve the MethodInfo for the correct overload of the generic `Enumerable.Any` method.
2. Construct the non-generic MethodInfo from the generic one (i.e., call `MakeGenericMethod`).
3. Construct the PropertyExpression that you will pass as the first argument to the method (representing `ctx.Invoce`)
4. Construct the body of the lambda expression that you will pass as the second argument to the method (i.e., `rightPart` in your example code).
5. Construct the LambdaExpression (e.g., `var innerLambda = Expression.Lambda(rightPart, i);`)
6. Construct the MethodCallExpression representing the call to the method, passing the MethodInfo and innerLambda.
7. Construct the LambdaExpression that you will pass to `Where` (i.e., `Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression, c)`.

The fourth step will vary if you want to combine boolean expressions as indicated in your comment.

I hope that helps.

Comment: ok, but I'm wondering how I can integrate my existing context to the expression

Comment: @PitMing as a ParameterExpression that you pass to the CallExpression.

Comment: I still don't get it as my expression need to be a binary expression I can combine with other filter I dynamicaly generate

Comment: @PitMing I've added a more detailed explanation of the process.

Answer (score 2):

Note that I've added inner expression.  There's a bit of closure code that you'd need to make, since you have a captured variable.

Note the simplification opportunity when using code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3472250/90475.

Minimal code to get the expression code in DebugView...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
   class CTX
   {
      public List<Customer> Invoices = new List<Customer>();
   }

   class Customer
   {
      public int id;
      public static bool HasMatchingIds(Customer first, Customer second) { return true; }
   }

   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         CTX ctx = new CTX();

         Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression = cust => ctx.Invoices.Any(customer => Customer.HasMatchingIds(customer, cust));
      }
   }
}
```

Here's what I see in the reflector:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ParameterExpression CS$0$0000;
    ParameterExpression CS$0$0002;
    CTX ctx = new CTX();
    Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(null, (MethodInfo) methodof(Enumerable.Any),
    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(ctx.Invoices), Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
    Expression.Call(null, (MethodInfo) methodof(Customer.HasMatchingIds), new Expression[] { 
    CS$0$0002 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "customer"),
    CS$0$0000 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "cust") }), 
    new ParameterExpression[] { CS$0$0002 }) }), new ParameterExpression[] { CS$0$0000 });
}
```

Close enough for government work...  This tells me that it's far from trivial, and you need to simplify your original query.

I would also try running LinqPad for quick prototyping

Comment: Maybee it's totally obvious to you, but not for me. What ere those 2 lambda, how can my context be a constant and how do I combine the all together +?

Comment: The original query seems not to be so complex... I think I'll have to build view so i can generate something simpler... Too bad

Comment: Building the lambda and using Reflector is a good way of working on this. But obviously I can't use the output... I'll get home very sad today...

Comment: @PitMing I took the liberty of simplifying your query somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code:

```
var any = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Any", new Type[] { typeof(Invoice) },
    Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.Constant(ctx), "Invoice"),
    Expression.Lambda(rightPart, i));
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(any, c);
```

Then you can use `filter` as a parameter in any `IQueryable<Customer>.Where` method.