# Can you pre-compile C# assemblies to allow fluent strongly typed, refactor friendly code and that is performant?

Tags: c#, reflection

Using strongly type names allows for refactor friendly code. Referencing names of properties, types, etc... generally involves reflection which adds overhead which in performance critical applications can be a problem.

Given the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0} is now running", typeof( Program ).Name );
Console.WriteLine( "{0} is now shutting down", typeof( Program ).Name );
```

Is there a way you can skip the reflection during execution? Is there a way to actually make the compiled code execute without the reflection calls?

```
Console.WriteLine( "{0} is now running", "Program" );
Console.WriteLine( "{0} is now shutting down", "Program" );
```

I've tried to use Reflection.Emit(), but can't quite seem to get what would be needed. Any suggestions or ideas would be great.

Comment: Roslyn can be used to do that.

Comment: Can you show us what your `Reflection.Emit()` attempts look like?

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof` operator and `Type.Name` property are both actually quite efficient. In this case, the overhead of `Console.WriteLine` vastly outweighs it.

For other types of code using "sneaky tricks" to avoid weakly-typed reflection (e.g. strings), such as using [expression trees to simulate a `methodof` or `fieldof` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1213862/138304), you can store the result in a `static readonly` field of a class, so they only need to be computed once.

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a variable to hold the value. That is, at startup:

```
string programName = typeof(Program).Name;
```

And then use `programName` wherever you need it.

The case you show is obviously a contrived example, as I doubt that you're worried about the runtime efficiency of a couple `Console.WriteLine` calls.

Without a more concrete example, it's really hard to give specific useful suggestions.