# Using Reflection to Invoke an Extension Method

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've created a MyFunc extension (in Module Extensions) for all the base types as well as generic arrays, ICollection(Of T) and Dictionary(Of String,T):

```
Function MyFunc(Of T)(a() As T) As String
Function MyFunc(Of T)(collection As ICollection(Of T)) As String
Function MyFunc(Of T)(dict As Dictionary(Of String,T)) As String
```

In most cases, I use the functions directly (i.e. "Test".MyFunc()) but there are late-bound situations for which I'm working on a generic function:

```
Function LateBoundMyFunc(val As Object) As String
  Dim t As Type = val.GetType
  If TypeOf val Is Array Then
    t = ????
  ElseIf TypeOf val Is ICollection
    t = ????
  ElseIf Typeof val Is Dictionary(Of String,) <- This fails
    t = ????
  End If
  Return CType(GetType(Extensions).GetMethod("MyFunc",New Type(){t}).Invoke(Nothing,New Object(){val}),String)
```

It's fairly simple to handle the base types, but what do I put in place of the ???? and how do I test for Dictionary(Of String,T)?

Comment: Is the question: "How do I check that `val` is of type `Dictionary(Of String, T)` where T is not known?"  Or do you know what type `T` should be?

Comment: @Pranay No it won't... the New Type(){t} must match the stored type for each of the generic functions - it acts as a lookup for GetMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot get generic methods without looping through all methods and selecting the one you want.  See this question:

[Get a generic method without using GetMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods)

Next, you cannot create and invoke a generic method without seating all generic parameters.  You must make `LateBoundMyFunc` a generic method, or alter it in some way to accept a value for the type of `T` for `Dictionary(Of String, T)`.  Once you have the method selected, you'll have to call `CreateGenericMethod` on it to seat those parameters.  This is just how reflections works.  You have to do all the work, and it can't figure out types for you.

The last problem is that any `Dictionary(Of String, T)` will *also* be a `ICollection`.  So you need to swap the order of those checks.