# How to Get Array.IndexOf<string>(string[], string) MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get `MethodInfo` for `Array.IndexOf<string>(string[], string)` ?

I try using this code, but doesn't work.

```
typeof(Array).GetMethod("IndexOf", 
 BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, 
  new Type[] { typeof(string[]), typeof(string) }, null);
```

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods).

Comment: Thanks for your additional information, that give me more understanding of my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select Right Generic Method with Reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631547/select-right-generic-method-with-reflection)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static`

**Edit:**

The comment below is correct, the problem is that the `IndexOf` method is generic - there is only a `Array.IndexOf<T>(T[], T)`. To get that one this is what worked for me:

```
var indexOfGeneric = typeof(Array).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                  .First(m => m.Name == "IndexOf" 
                                           && m.GetParameters().Length == 2
                                           && m.IsGenericMethod );
```

Comment: This will return Array.IndexOf(Array, Object) MethodInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Found this blog post that seems to achieve what you're asking for;

http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/10/getting-methodinfo-of-generic-method.html

Sample usage would be as follows;

```
var m = SymbolExtensions.GetMethodInfo(() => Array.IndexOf<string>(null, null));
```

This way, you get the `MethodInfo` of `IndexOf<String>(String[], String)`, instead of `IndexOf<T>(T[], T)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I love the lamda and strongtyped method selector.