# C# use reflection to get method name

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, reflection, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get methodinfo from a method reference C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382216/get-methodinfo-from-a-method-reference-c-sharp)

This is most likely something simple but so far I have not come up with anything on how to do this.

I want to be able to get the name of a method in two different ways. Please note I want a method name, not a property name.

1) Inside of a class like `ClassA<T>`, looking like:

```
var name = GetMethodName(x => x.MethodA);
```

2) Outside of a class, looking like:

```
var name = GetMethodName<ClassA<object>>(x => x.MethodA);
var name = GetMethodName<ClassB>(x => x.MethodB);
```

How might I do this exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need lambdas (`x => x.MethodA`, etc). That's just confusing the issue (and hiding the method of interest: the `MethodA` bit would be hidden from your `GetMethodName` method).

Instead, you can use reflection to get a `MethodInfo` object, which then has a `Name` property.

For example:

```
MethodInfo sm = typeof(SomeClass).GetMethod("SomeMethod");
string methodName = sm.Name;
```

Here `methodName` will be the string `"SomeMethod"`. (Of course, in this simple case we've used the class name to get the `MethodInfo` object, so it's somewhat circular and we might as well have just used the hard-coded `"SomeMethod"` string instead!)

Comment: This will not work for me, that is why I said I need it using a lambda expression. Reflection using strings does not work once obfuscated as the method names change from "MethodA" to "ASNDKAMSDKMASD" for example. If I use it like my example, then when the method name is renamed the reflection does not break. That is why I must be able to do it using the way I asked for.

Comment: Okay, I didn't realise it was possible to retrieve the target method from a lambda expression but it appears it is. See the possible duplicate question I've linked to in my comment above.

Comment: Thanks, I think that will solve my issue!