# Mocking a protected generic method with Moq

Tags: moq

To mock a protected virtual (non-generic) method in Moq is easy:

```
public class MyClass
{
....
      protected virtual int MyMethod(Data data){..}
}
```

And to mock it:

```
myMock.Protected().Setup<int>("MyMethod", ItExpr.Is<Data>( ...
```

I could not find a way to use the same technique if the protected method is generic, like:

```
protected virtual int MyMethod<T>(T data)
```

Any idea how to do it, besides using a wrapper class to override that method, is highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can.  The first thing I tried was passing MyMethod`1[T] to Setup(), but that didn't seem to fool it.  You might try playing with that, anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've checked the source and it seems **mocking protected generic methods with Moq is not supported**:

The `Protected()` method creates an instance of a class `ProtectedMock<T>` which uses the following method to get the method that you want to mock:

```
private static MethodInfo GetMethod(string methodName, params object[] args)
{
    return typeof(T).GetMethod(
           methodName,
           BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public,
           null,
           ToArgTypes(args),
           null);
}
```

It uses [Type.GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) to get the method for mocking, but `GetMethod` (although MSDN states differently) don't play nice with generics, see:

[GetMethod for generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method)

[Get a generic method without using GetMethods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods)

Side note:
In my opinion mocking a protected member is a code smell, and I would rather try to avoid it anyway with refactoring my design (beside that it's not supported in Moq).

Comment: I totally agree with the code smell. But sometimes in a more complex scenario this can easy the testing. I.e. if you have very "similar" functionality for a bunch of methods, and you really just want to verify the the publicly exposed parts do map properly the parameters to pass them down.

Answer (score 6):

It can be done since Moq 4.13 (2019-09-01) by using `As` for protected methods and `It.IsAnyType` for generic type arguments:

`classUnderTest.Protected().As<IMyMethodMock>().Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>())).Returns(...);`

And create the following interface for the mocking method:

```
public interface IMyMethodMock
{
    int MyMethod<T>(T data);
}
```

Full example:

```
[TestClass]
public class MockingProtectedGenericFixture
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var classUnderTest = new Mock<MyClass>();
        classUnderTest.Protected().As<IMyMethodMock>().Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>())).Returns(2);

        // Act
        var resForStringData = classUnderTest.Object.GetNumber("DataString");
        var resForBooleanData = classUnderTest.Object.GetNumber(true);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, resForStringData);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, resForBooleanData);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int GetNumber<T>(T data)
    {
        return MyMethod(data);
    }

    protected virtual int MyMethod<T>(T data)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public interface IMyMethodMock
{
    int MyMethod<T>(T data);
}
```

Comment: fantastic! worked like a charm!