# .net Mock a method that has a generic return type

Tags: .net, generics, moq

I'm trying to Mock a method that has a generic return type that is implemented in an abstract class.

Abstract class code:

```
public abstract class AbstractRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected virtual async Task<T> GetById(int id)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

Implementation class:

```
public class UserRepository : AbstractRepository<User>
{
    public Task<User> GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return base.GetById(id);
    }
}
```

Test method:

```
[Theory]
public async Task GetUserById_UserExists_ReturnsUser(User user)
{
    Mock<UserRepository> mockRealSut = new(MockBehavior.Strict, new object[] {
    })
    {
        CallBase = true
    };

    //Setup Mock
    
    //Act
    User result = await mockRealSut.Object.GetUserById(1);
}
```

I'm not being able to successfully setup the Mock, as the actual real abstract method IS ALWAYS called.

I've tried 2 approaches:

Approach 1:

```
_ = mockRealSut.Protected().Setup<Task<User>>("GetById", ItExpr.IsAny<int>()).ReturnsAsync(user);
```

Approach 2:

```
public interface IGetByIdMethodMock<T>
{
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
}

_ = mockRealSut.Protected().As<IGetByIdMethodMock<User>>().Setup(m => m.GetById(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
```

This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416291/mocking-a-protected-generic-method-with-moq) on stackoverflow seems to indicate that approach 2) should have worked, but its specific to a generic parameter, and not a generic return type.

I've looked into Moq documentation, but i can't find a solution for this.

Am i missing something?
I assume this should be possible with Moq, but something is missing and i can't find the problem.

This type of CRUD approach is very common, so it would be strange if Moq wouldn't cover this type of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `GetUserById` method calls `base.GetById`:

```
return base.GetById(id);
```

This means that it explicitly calls `AbstractRepository<User>.GetById`, not `UserRepository.GetById`.

When you ask Moq to override `UserRepository.GetById` you do that, but you don't override `AbstractRepository<User>.GetById`.

Change the `GetUserById` method to this:

```
public Task<User> GetUserById(int id)
{
    return GetById(id);
}
```

Then a test like this works:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1)]
[InlineData(2)]
public async Task GetUserById(int id)
{
    var expected = new User();
    var repo = new Mock<UserRepository>();
    repo.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<User>>("GetById", ItExpr.Is<int>(i => i == id))
        .ReturnsAsync(expected);

    var actual = await repo.Object.GetUserById(id);

    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```