# Correct Parameter Type for GetMethod

Tags: c#, reflection

In the code below, how should I be setting the variable "paramType" so that it matches the method shown in the GetMethod() call?

The code below does NOT match the method in the sample class (methodInfo is null).

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class MyClass<TClass>
{
    public void MyMethod<TMethod>( Expression<Func<TClass, TMethod>> expr )
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var classType = typeof( MyClass<> );

        // What should this really be?
        var paramType = typeof( Expression<> ).MakeGenericType( typeof( Func<,> ) );

        var methodInfo = classType.GetMethod( "MyMethod", new Type[] { paramType } );
    }
}
```

EDIT: I know how to get the `MethodInfo` using `GetMethods` or some other form of iteration / assumption. My question is specifically about how to set the `System.Type` of `paramType`, if its even possible to generate a `System.Type` for it.

EDIT 2: To be more specific with the problem, I've updated the code with more flavor:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class MyClass<TClass>
{
    public void MyMethod<TMethod>( Expression<Func<TClass, TMethod>> expr )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Type: {0}   Return: {1}", typeof( TClass ).Name, typeof( TMethod ).Name );
    }

    public void MyMethod<TMethod>( TMethod param )
    {
    }
}

class Program
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }

    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var classType = typeof( MyClass<> );

        var typeClass = typeof( Program );
        var typeMethod = typeof( int );

        // What should this really be?
        var paramType = typeof( Expression<> )
                 .MakeGenericType( typeof( Func<,> )
                                   .MakeGenericType( typeClass, typeMethod )
                                 );

        var methodInfo = classType
                        .MakeGenericType( typeClass )
                        .GetMethod( "MyMethod", new Type[] { paramType } );
    }
}
```

This doesn't work either- this different version of `paramType` with more information doesn't seem to match.

In the non-general case, someone may want to call "MyMethod" like this:

```
// I want to use a MethodInfo to perform this function:
new MyClass<Program>().MyMethod( _program => _program.MyProperty );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods

Comment: Thanks for the references, but neither of these answers my specific question. One answer seems to involve iterating through a Type's members, while the other doesn't nest a generic type within another generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is, "There is no way to do this".

Since GetMethod is not able to "MakeGenericMethod" while its doing its lookup, you have a method with one generic parameter that's known (TClass) and one that's not (TMethod). Reflection can't look up a method when some, but not all, of the parameters are known.

Note- Even though you **do** know what TMethod is supposed to be ("int" in your example), this would require the "MakeGenericMethod" that I referenced in the previous paragraph.

Comment: I think this is the case as well- I can't find any better answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to know the generic types, I don't think your task would be possible otherwise.

If your intention was to create a generic methodinfo for a generic class, before it knows any of its types, so you can later call `MakeGenericType` with your two types on it, that won't possible.

This can be shown by calling `typeof(MyClass<>).GetMethod("MyMethod")`, which will return null.

If you know the specific types on the other hand, that's easy:

```
static MethodInfo GetMethod(Type classType, Type methodType)
{
    var genericClassType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(classType);
    var methodInfo = genericClassType.GetMethod("MyMethod");
    var genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(methodType);
    return genericMethodInfo;
}
```

Notice that I don't create a generic type for the `Expression<Func<TClass,TMethod>>` parameter.

When you create the `genericClassType` and call `GetMethod` on it, the CLR doesn't know yet, what type `TMethod` would be. This is only know as soon as you call `MakeGenericType` on `methodInfo`. Therefore if you would call `GetMethod` with a fully parametrized `Expression<Func<TClass,TMethod>>` type, it wouldn't find the method.

That's why you need to call `genericClassType.GetMethod("MyMethod")` without the parameter types and possibly have to filter it, if the method is overloaded. Afterwards you can call `MakeGenericMethod(methodType)` and have your fully parametrized methodInfo object.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't exactly what I need. I'll edit the question again with more background.

Comment: More specifically- the `GetMethod` without Type parameters will be ambiguous, which is why I need the Type parameter in the first place.

Comment: You will not be able to call GetMethod with for a generic Method, whose parameters are depending on the generic method type (which is what you are trying to do). There's no way for the CLR to know which type the generic method would have, before calling MakeGenericMethod on it. Therefore you need to call GetMethod without the parameters and need to iterate through all found Methods if necessary. There is no better way sadly, you can't create a generic type with reflection, wheres on of the type parameters is not yet set.