# C# GetMethod info of Queryable class

Tags: c#, reflection, types, typeof, getmethod

I'm new at Reflection and I was trying the below peice of code

```
var queryableLastMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("Last", new Type[]{ typeof(IQueryable<>) });
```

but *queryableLastMethodInfo* always returns *null*.

Could you please help?

Comment: @RafaelDiaz: huh? Methods don't have namespaces.

Comment: I do have to wonder what exactly the plan is with this particular piece of code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the MethodInfo of the "Last" extension method that doesn't take a predicate:

```
var queryableLastMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Last" && x.GetParameters().Count() == 1);
```

...and this should give you the other one:

```
var queryableLastMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Last" && x.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all *Last* methods and select the one with only one parameter:

```
var method = typeof (Queryable).GetMethods()
                               .Where(m => m.Name == "Last")
                               .First(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 1);
```

Generic case is described in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269578/get-a-generic-method-without-using-getmethods).

Answer (score 0):

Don't take risk code failed if Queryable receuve new methods called "Last" and taking only one parameter.

Accurate is never to much.

```
var queryableLastMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(_Method => _Method.Name == "Last" && _Method.IsGenericMethod && _Method.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1 && _Method.GetParameters().Length == 1   && _Method.GetParameters().Single().ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(_Method.GetGenericArguments().Single()));
```