# c# Enumerable Reflection GetMethod not found method

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have code for getting method Select for Enumerable.

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Select", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, [typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(Func<,>)]);
```

I getting null. But when i debbugging in source code was method as candidate with exact types as IEnumerable and Func but they were slightly different like they don't have AssemblyQualifiedName and some other fields, it was RuntimeType or something as i know, and as result type which getting in source code is not assignable from type what in method parameters.

I tried other types, but it alsways null.

```
typeof(IEnumerable<>)
typeof(IEnumerable)
typeof(Enumerable)
```

I can get method like that and it working.

```
var selectMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Select))
            .First(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(elementType, elementType);
```

But i interested why GetMethod not working in that case

Comment: A) `.MakeGenericMethod(elementType, elementType);` won't work since both Enumerable.Select overloads with two parameters have parameters of different type (IEnumerable<T> and Func<>). So you'd need to pass two different types, not `elementType` twice.
B) `.First(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2)`  returns a random overload, either the one with `Func<TSource,TResult>` or the one with `Func<TSource,int, TResult>`.
You shoudl also query the 2nd type to ensure MakeGenericMethod will work.

Comment: In my case it will always be same type, so it work for my project pretty well. I write some tests and all well. I more interested why GetMethod not working

Comment: @ferry you provided your own answer :) "they were slightly different"... I'm pretty sure https://stackoverflow.com/a/68642630/477420 from the linked duplicate is  the answer to have them exactly the same. If not - go through all answers in those two and possibly [edit] this question to clarify what parts did not work in your case/you need to be explained.

Comment: @ferry okay you were right.
The reason that your first query with GetMethod doesn't work is that you need to make the type-array an array of parameter types. See "Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter" and this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrPDl9